# Using lambda function to modify class

Tags: c++, class, lambda

I am currently trying to use `std::transform()` on a vector that contains smart pointers to a class named `Triangle`, in which I have several methods that change `Triangle` parameters.

Now I want to make my life easier and use `std::transform()` with my own lambda function and apply it to every dynamically allocated triangle.

However, I ran into a problem when trying to access private attributes of my class inside that very lambda function.
I am curious how can I overcome this issue?

```
typedef std::pair<double, double> Point;

//the class Triangle contains these methods:

class Triangle{
    Point t1, t2, t3;
public:
    Trougao(const Point &t1, const Point &t2, const Point &t3){
        if(Triangle::Orijentacija(t1,t2,t3)==0) 
            throw std::domain_error("Incorrect vertices");
        Triangle::t1.first=t1.first;
        Triangle::t1.second=t1.second;
        Triangle::t2.first=t2.first;
        Triangle::t2.second=t2.second;
        Triangle::t3.first=t3.first;
        Triangle::t3.second=t3.second;
    }

    void Set(const Point &t1, const Point &t2, const Point &t3){
        if(Triangle::Orientation(t1,t2,t3)==0)
            throw std::domain_error("Incorrect vertices");
        Triangle::t1.first=t1.first;
        Triangle::t1.second=t1.second;
        Triangle::t2.first=t2.first;
        Triangle::t2.second=t2.second;
        Triangle::t3.first=t3.first;
        Triangle::t3.second=t3.second;
    }

    void Set(int indeks, const Point &t){
        if(indeks!=1 && indeks!=2 && indeks!=3)
            throw std::range_error("Incorrect index");
        if(indeks==1){
            this->t1.first=t.first;
            this->t1.second=t.second;
        }
        else if(indeks==2){
            this->t2.first=t.first;
            this->t2.second=t.second;
        }
        else if (indeks==3){
            this->t3.first=t.first;
            this->t3.second=t.second;
        }
    }

    Point GiveVertex(int indeks) const{
        if(indeks!=1 && indeks!=2 && indeks!=3)
            throw std::range_error("Incorrect index");
        if(indeks==1) return Triangle::t1;
        else if(indeks==2) return Triangle::t2;
        else if(indeks==3) return Triangle::t3;
    }

    void Translate(double delta_x, double delta_y){
        t1.first+=delta_x;
        t1.second+=delta_y;
        t2.first+=delta_x;
        t2.second+=delta_y;
        t3.first+=delta_x;
        t3.second+=delta_y;
    }
};

//now I would like to make in my main program a vector of smart pointers 
//which I would use do dyn. alloc. "n" Triangles. After that I want to use 
//std::transform to Translate every single one (with lambda function)
//I am currently stuck at implementation of this lambda function as you can 
// see:
//-------------(main)------------------------------
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"How many triangles: ";
    std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<double> translation_vector(2);
    double angle, scale_faktor;
    Point dot1, dot2, dot3; 
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Triangle>> vect_smrt_ptr(n);
    for(int i(0); i<n; i++){
        std::cout<<"Input data for the"<<i+1<<". triangle (x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3):";
        std::cin>>dot1.first>>dot1.second>>dot2.first>>dot2.second>>dot3.first>>dot3.second;
        std::shared_ptr<Triangle> smrt_ptr(new Triangle(dot1, dot2, dot3));
        vect_smrt_ptr.at(i)=smrt_ptr;
    }
    std::cout<<"Input translation vector (dx dy): ";
    std::cin>>translation_vector.at(0)>>translation_vector.at(1);

    //now the tricky part!
    std::transform(&vect_smrt_ptr.at(0), &vect_smrt_ptr.at(vect_smrt_ptr.size()), &vect_smrt_ptr.at(0),
        [translation_vector](Triangle tr){ tr.Translate(translation_vector.at(0), translation_vector.at(1)); }
    );
```

Comment: Why not use the simplest code for this:  `for (auto& p : vect_smrt_ptr) p->Translate(translation_vector.at(0), translation_vector.at(1));`?  `transform` isn't a clean, minimal fit for what you're trying to achieve....  If you particularly want to use a Standard Library algo with a lambda, [`for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is the natural fit: `std::for_each(vect_smart_ptr.begin(), vect_smart_ptr.end(), [&](auto& p) { p->Translate(...); });`.

Comment: Hmm I get what you want to do, but now I have this message from a compiler when I start the code: (actually it reffers to the codeblocks stl_construct.h) : // (title) Constructs an object in existing memory by invoking an allocated
object's constructor with an initializer .//

Comment: Maybe I should mention that i currently use c++11 so no auto declaratons in lambda function :/

Comment: Humm, this question look very much as another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434095/class-attributes-appear-private-to-lambda-functions. **Even asked by the same person!**

Comment: @kenobe: no need to get sad about the lack of support for `auto` there - can just use `std::shared_ptr<Triangle>&` or even `vect_smart_ptr::value_type&`.  I can't make sense of the compiler error message you're reporting.  Better append the exact code you're trying with and the full error message to your question....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class attributes appear private to lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434095/class-attributes-appear-private-to-lambda-functions)

Comment: I know that my last question was badly shaped and I apologize for that, I just want to clarify my issue the best I can

Comment: Honestly kenobe, posting the question again is disingenuous.  People explained last time you should create a minimal, complete program that reproduces the problem.  This "300 lines long" thing is nonsense: you could create a new triangle class with just a `Translate` function - it wouldn't even need to do anything sensible to the triangle - in less than 20 lines of code.  If that didn't fail the way your larger code did, you can start reasoning about the differences.

Comment: There... I did what was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::transform` is not a good choice in your case, because it's supposed to convert one collection of objects into another collection (of course in particular case, output collection can be the same as input collection). Like this:

```
std::transform(inputCollection.begin(), inputCollection.end(), outputCollection.begin(),
    [](YourClass obj) {
        YourClass modified = ApllySomeModification(obj);
        return modified;
    });
```

In your case `std::for_each` is a better algorithm:

```
std::for_each(vect_smrt_ptr.begin(), vect_smrt_ptr.end(),
    [translation_vector](std::shared_ptr<Triangle> tr) {
        tr->Translate(translation_vector.at(0), translation_vector.at(1));
    });
```

because it has a semantics of modifying your elements in-place.